# How to make the Google client api connection?

Tags: android, android-googleapiclient

I am facing the issue in creating the google api client connection preference screen. The google api client is connected success in the oncreateView() method but my problem is the google api client must connect when the preference switch is on the google api should connect.

```
  mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
            .addApi(Drive.API)
            .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();
```

The above works fine when it is placed inside the oncreateView().

```
    record.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValues) {

                if (((Boolean) newValues)) {
 mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
                .addApi(Drive.API)
                .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();

                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Connection On", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Connection OFF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                return true;
            }
        });
```

In above code google api client connection is placed inside the preference switch is not working the exception is occurring.Please help me how to solve this.

This exception is shown when the preference switch is clicked

```
 E/MessageQueue-JNI: Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
06-30 12:45:59.810 4029-4029/com.seyali.callLog E/MessageQueue-JNI: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.seyali.callLog.SettingsActivity cannot be cast to com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient$ConnectionCallbacks
                                                                        at com.seyali.callLog.PreferenceFragments$4.onPreferenceClick(PreferenceFragments.java:233)
                                                                        at android.preference.Preference.performClick(Preference.java:996)
                                                                        at android.preference.PreferenceScreen.onItemClick(PreferenceScreen.java:249)
```

Comment: Post the exception here

Comment: @ akhilesh0707  I posted the exception

Comment: this refers to current context. Try with retrieving application context and apply to methods which accepts context

Comment: @  Stallion i tried your answer, not working

Comment: @ Stallion  The google api connected success when it is implemented  onCreateview() but when is placed in onclick on preference switch it is not working ,showing exception.

Answer (score 0):

Implement the **GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks** and **GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener** in activity like this

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {}
```

Comment: public class PreferenceFragments extends PreferenceFragment implements
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

Comment: I added this callback interface in a fragment

Comment: It will ask permission if you are working in marshmallow devices

Comment: @  HsRaja  I am working in max sdk version 25 and minimum sdk version 19

Comment: How to create the permission

Comment: settings-->your app -->give permission for location